# If distance between the two sets is zero then their intersection is empty?

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A$ and $B$ two non-empty sets in 
>   $X$.
>
> If $d(A,B)= 0$ then, is their intersection empty?

I attempted this problem writing:

$d(A, B)=\inf\left\{ d(x,y): x\in A, y\in B\right\}=0 \implies d(x,y)= 0 \implies x=y$

That is, if $d(A,B) = 0$ then there exists $x \in A \cap B$, so the intersection is not empty!

My question is whether I am taking the infimum wrong or doing anything else wrongly? How can I show this with an example?

Comment: Well, the intersection could be empty, but it need not be. You seem to be assuming that the infimum is attained inside the set, which it need not (consider for example the disjoint intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ on the real like).

Comment: So is there no final conclusion about their intersection?

Comment: No, your conclusion that $A\cap B$ is non-empty is wrong. What you can say is that there exists a point $c$ such that $c$ is a limit point in both $A$ and $B$. For example $\mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R^-$ have distance $0$, but there is no real number that is both positive and negative (but a limit point $0$ exists to both sets).

Comment: @skyking Not even that, for the limit point can be "missing" from $X$. Think of $A = \{(x_1, 0) \mid x_1 \in \mathbf R\}$, and $B = \{x \mid x_1 x_2 = 1\}$ in $X = \mathbf R^2$.

Comment: @martini My bad, there's a sequence in $A$ and $B$ such that $\lim d(a_j, b_j) = 0$. You need $A$ and $B$ to be part of a compact set to get a limit point (unless I'm mistaken again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any further assumption on $A$ and $B$, there is no conclusion about their intersection:

- In $X = \def\R{\mathbf R}\R$ with the euclidian metric, $A = [0,1]$ and $B = (1,2)$ have $d(A,B) = 0$ and empty intersection, but $A$ and $B' = [1,2]$ have also $d(A, B') = 0$.
- Even if we suppose $A$ and $B$ to be closed, we can have $d(A,B) = 0$ with empty intersection. Consider $A = \R \times \{0\}$ and $B= \{x \in \R^2 \mid x_1 x_2 = 1\}$. Here $d(A,B) = 0$ due to $d(a_n, b_n) = \frac 1n$ for $a_n = (n,0) \in A$ and $b_n = (n, \frac 1n) \in B$.
- If we suppose $A$ to be *compact* and $B$ to be closed, something can be said. It that case, we have that $d(A,B) = 0$ implies $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$. For choose $a_n \in A$ and $b_n \in B$ such that $d(a_n, b_n) \to d(A,B)=0$. As $A$ is compact $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, we may suppose w. l. o. g. that $a_n \to a \in A$. As $d(a_n, b_n) \to 0$, we have that 
  $$ d(b_n, a) \le d(a_n, b_n) + d(a_n,a) \to 0 $$
  that is $b_n \to a$. As $B$ is closed, $a \in B$, that is $a\in A \cap B$.